# How to work on a forked repository (package) locally in docker?

Tags: git, docker, repository

So I forked a repository but how do I go about working on the repo locally? I cloned it into the project folder, but not sure what to do next. Google results are horrible. Keep showing me docker repos.

The package i want to make some changes to is this one
https://github.com/arneb/django-messages

I am using docker and install all my third party apps via pipenv.

I tried cd into the project folder and using pipenv install -e . where the setup.py file is, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that on the docker image, git is installed (if incase not installed).

After you cloned the project. Simply go to that directory

`$ cd django-messages/`

and if simply do a `ls -la` , you should see all the files including the .git file as well. Then should be possible to work on the project

Comment: yes I got to that part, but how do I go about using that project with my django project? It won't let me run setup.py. When i run ``winpty docker-compose exec web pipenv setup.py install`` it says, No such command 'setup.py'.